# How to override JS function in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Trying to override the handlerOut (mouseleave) effect from another function:

```
 $( '.main-nav .menu-item' ).hover(
                    function() {
                            $( '> .sub-menu' , this )
                                    .stop( true, true )
                                    .fadeIn( { duration: 250 } );

                    }, function() {
                            $( '> .sub-menu' , this )
                                    .stop( true, true )
                                    .fadeOut( { duration: 250 } );
            } );
```

I don't want the elements to fade out but not sure how to override this. Is it possible to stop the hover effect from happening using another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the event handlers using [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and attach your own instead. You have to make sure that your script runs **after** the other script.

> Note : [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) works for jQuery 1.7 or newer, if you are using an older version see [`.unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

```js
$('.main-nav .menu-item')
  .off('mouseenter mouseleave')
  .hover( /* your own hover functions */ );
```

or just the mouseleave event if you don't want to change the over effect:

```js
$('.main-nav .menu-item')
  .off('mouseleave')
  .mouseleave( /* your own hiding function */ );
```

Comment: I have tried this but anytime I mouseleave from any child element of $('.main-van .menu-item') the UL still collapses. Is there a way to prioritize my second function to be the one that gets applied?

Comment: Are you sure your code is running after the original code? Your script should be included after the original script and if the original code is executed on `ready` your code needs to do the same: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: yeah, it's right beneath the main.js file call where the original code is set.

Comment: You need animations somewhere else, right? If not you could disable jQuery animations as a workaround: `jQuery.fx.off=true;`.

Comment: ended up moving the function from the main file over to the functions file. Not ideal but I just can't override that JS code for some reason. Thank you for the info provided though. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just disable mouseleave event by calling `.off('mouseleave')`, additionally if you want to do some other work, use `.mouseleave`

```
$('.main-nav .menu-item').off('mouseleave').mouseleave( function () {
  console.log('now it will not fadeout on mousle leave');
});
```

Comment: As noted on the first answer above, I have tried this but anytime I mouseleave from any child element of $('.main-van .menu-item') the UL still collapses. Is there a way to prioritize my second function to be the one that gets applied?